# Recoger nombre de un ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

el problema que tengo es el siguiente:
Tengo un listView el cual desde la clase ModulosAdapter lo lleno. Cada fila se compone 2 textView uno es el nombre del modulo y otro el estado.

Los datos los obtengo de una base de datos precargada la cual tiene 6 modulos con sus respectivos estados que son o "Pendiente" o "Aprobado".

Lo que quiero hacer es en el Activity donde se carga el listView al dar click a uno de los modulos recoger el nombre para hacer un select del `ID` y poder editarlo en otro activity.

(El toast es solamente para comprobar si me coge el nombre o no, pero nada no funciona)

En el activity donde se carga el `listView` esta asi:

```
public class ConsultaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GestorPersistencia gp;
    ModulosAdapter ma;
    private Toolbar tbActionBar;
    private ListView lvListaModulos;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.consulta_modulos);


        tbActionBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tbActionBar);
        lvListaModulos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvListaModulos);


        setSupportActionBar(tbActionBar);


        gp = new GestorPersistencia(this);
        Cursor cursor = gp.getModulos();


        ma = new ModulosAdapter(this, cursor);
        lvListaModulos.setAdapter(ma);


        lvListaModulos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String nombreModulo = lvListaModulos.getItemAtPosition(position).toString;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),nombreModulo,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                //Intent intent = new Intent(ConsultaActivity.this,EdicionModulo.class);

            }
        });
```

Comment: "recoger el nombre para hacer un select del ID", a que id te refieres?

Comment: Tu ModulosAdapter recibe un cursor con que datos? me iamgino que alli va el nombre y el ID que quieres, de ser asi tendrias que volver a recorrerlo para obtener el ID

Comment: Al ID del item seleccionado en el listView, porque al pinchar en el elemento quiero poder editar su "Estado" en otro activity.

Comment: El adaptador recibe el nombre del modulo y su estado. El ID lo pillaria consultandolo en la base de datos con un "SELECT" y el nombre